# plot with R personalized

Tags: r, plot

I try to do a plot with R with the command below, but I got the line between 0 and 20. How can I precise that the first value 32.2 correspond to 10 (abcissa), the second value 32.2 correspond to 20 (abcissa)?

```
Deuxgrammes <- c(32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2)
plot(Deuxgrammes, type="o", col="blue", xlim =c(0,100), ylim=c(26,33))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, at least one simple way, is you can also define x values as

```
x = seq( from = 10, by = 10, length.out = length( Deuxgrammes ) )
```

and then just plot them.

```
plot (x, Deuxgrammes, type="o", col="blue", xlim = c(0,100),  ylim=c(26,33))
```

In addition to that, if the axes differ, you can change the labels.